# jquery - scattering images within a defined space so they don't overlap

Tags: jquery, image, random, position, overlapping

Hello to all coders of quality and others!

I am using a jquery script (Author: Marco Kuiper - www.marcofolio.net) that randomly places images within a defined space. Using a mouse the images can be dragged around on the screen, then clicked to enlarge.

The problem is when the page is viewed on an iphone, the images cannot be dragged so if any images are overlapping they cannot be easily tapped and enlarged. My idea is to create an array of random coordinates that are at least the width of each image away from each other while still fitting with the confines of the enclosing div. The images are all the same dimensions. Once that array is created, use it's values to position the images.

Here's the current script that places the images:

```
        $(".polaroid").each
(function ()
    {
    var tempVal = Math.round(Math.random());
    if(tempVal == 1)
        { var rotDegrees = randomXToY(330, 360); } // rotate left
    else
        { var rotDegrees = randomXToY(0, 30); } // rotate right

    var position = $(this).parent().offset();
    var wiw = $(this).parent().width(); // width of div enclosing object
    var wih = $(this).parent().height(); // heiht of div enclosing object

    var leftpos = Math.random()*(wiw - $(this).width()) + position.left;
    var toppos = Math.random()*(wih - $(this).height()) + position.top;

    var cssObj =
        {
        'left' : leftpos,
        'top' : toppos,
        '-webkit-transform' : 'rotate('+ rotDegrees +'deg)',  // safari only
        '-moz-transform' : 'rotate('+ rotDegrees +'deg)',  // firefox only
        'tranform' : 'rotate('+ rotDegrees +'deg)' // if CSS3 is standard
        };
    $(this).css(cssObj);
    }
);
```

My scripting skills are not quite sufficient for this, so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason the images can't be laid out in a grid for mobile, but randomly scattered for everyone else?

Comment: Sure, I'd be fine with the images in a grid for mobile screens. I would like to keep the slight random rotations however.

Answer (score 0):

I'd need to see your HTML and CSS to help with the grid layout, but as far as the javascript goes, and if random rotation will suffice, you can just remove the bits about positioning:

```
$(".polaroid").each
  (function ()
    {
    var tempVal = Math.round(Math.random());
    if(tempVal == 1)
        { var rotDegrees = randomXToY(330, 360); } // rotate left
    else
        { var rotDegrees = randomXToY(0, 30); } // rotate right

    var cssObj =
        {
        '-webkit-transform' : 'rotate('+ rotDegrees +'deg)',  // safari only
        '-moz-transform' : 'rotate('+ rotDegrees +'deg)',  // firefox only
        'tranform' : 'rotate('+ rotDegrees +'deg)' // if CSS3 is standard
        };
    $(this).css(cssObj);
    }
  );
```

Comment: Thanks, I wish it had been that simple. If the HTML included <UL>'s it probably would have worked. But alas, it does not. Here's the HTML:

Comment: <div id="PolaroidWrapper">
<div id="polaroidcontainer">

 <div class="polaroid">
  <a href="images/image1.jpg"><img src="images/TN_image1.jpg" /></a>
 </div>
 
 <div class="polaroid">
  <a href="images/image2.jpg"><img src="images/TN_image2.jpg" /></a>
 </div>
 
 <div class="polaroid">
  <a href="images/image3.jpg"><img src="images/TN_image3.jpg" /></a>
 </div>

</div>
</div>

Comment: and the CSS:

        #PolaroidWrapper { width:700px; margin:0 auto; }
#polaroidcontainer { width:700px; height:600px; }
.polaroid
 {
 width:147px;
 height:150px;
 background-image:url(gallery/images/polaroid-bg.png); // image of polaroid photo frame
 position:absolute;

 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
 box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
 }
.polaroid img { width:134px; height:110px; margin:11px 0 0 7px; }

Comment: Ah, yes. Each image is wrapped in a div, which is a block-level element, so you'll need to float them in the CSS. Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/4MJmf/

Comment: Thank you very much, sorry it took me so long to get back to this. Your solution works great!

Comment: Better late than never! Mark it answered when you get a chance.